# I want to update my column attributes names without changing their values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1.I want a query to update my column attribute names without changing my attribute values.

This is what i have....
my table name is CheckIn and my column is name cravings:

```
my attributes:
`"Magic box"=>nil, "Play Store, fruits"=>nil, "Chocos"=>nil, "Sauces"=>nil, "Sugar"=>nil`
```

What i want is to rename my:

```
"Magic box"=>'Boundry wall',
"Play Store, fruits"=>'B Area',
"chocos"=>'raffle',
"Sauces"=>'ketchup',
"Sugar"=>'wheat'
```

just want to change/update my attributes names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
CheckIn.where.not(cravings: nil).each do |r|
  r.cravings['dairy'] = r.cravings.delete('Dairy products')
  .
  .
  .
  r.save!
end
```

Please, consider to use a transaction to rollback the updates upon failure.

Also note that it can take a long time depending on the size or your table. Check [each_record](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches/BatchEnumerator.html#method-i-each_record) to improve performance.

Comment: cravings is a column in my table checkins and inside it these are further columns such as dairy products, vegetables etc, so isn't there any query which i run on console to update my existing columns which are already created

Comment: Are you serializating data into `cravings`?

Comment: here is like i have CheckIn table inside it i have cravings column that cravings column consists of different fields like dairy products etc and i want to rename those fields

Comment: please look at the link it has an image which will clear it to you

Comment: do i need to create a new migration for it or i can do it in my existing changing column name migration?

Comment: and after that i have to just rails db:migrate to update my cravings?

Comment: You can use your existing migration, and yes, just run the migration. Anyway, I'd test a single update on the console just to make sure it works.

Comment: it worked thanks but the order is changed why is that so?

Comment: The order is set by the order you made the insertions (`craving['new_key'] = ...`)